# Set ImageView source on click with RemoteViews

Tags: android, onclick, android-imageview, remoteview, android-remoteview

Is there a way to set an imageview's source on click with remoteviews. I know you can do
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.source);

but that does not allow me to do it on click.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> but that does not allow me to do it on click

Yes, it does. Call `setOnClickPendingIntent()` on the `ImageView` entry in the `RemoteViews`, using a `PendingIntent` pointing to your `AppWidgetProvider` or another `BroadcastReceiver`. In there, call `setImageResource()` to update your `ImageView` and push the updates to the home screen via an `AppWidgetManager`.

For example, this sample `AppWidgetProvider` updates a pair of `ImageView` widgets with a fresh random dice roll when the user taps on either of the dice:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.appwidget.dice;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
  private static final int[] IMAGES={R.drawable.die_1,R.drawable.die_2,
                                      R.drawable.die_3,R.drawable.die_4,
                                      R.drawable.die_5,R.drawable.die_6};

  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager mgr,
                        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    ComponentName me=new ComponentName(ctxt, AppWidget.class);

    mgr.updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(ctxt, appWidgetIds));
  }

  private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context ctxt, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews updateViews=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
                                            R.layout.widget);

    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, AppWidget.class);

    i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0 , i,
                                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.left_die,
                                     IMAGES[(int)(Math.random()*6)]); 
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.left_die, pi);
    updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.right_die,
                                     IMAGES[(int)(Math.random()*6)]); 
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.right_die, pi);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.background, pi);

    return(updateViews);
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/PairOfDice))